# Wordpress using wrong template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I have installed Wordpress multisite (5.5.1) and created some custom post types. I have also created some custom templates.

Custom post type: "illustration"

Template file: illustration.php

The template file is empty apart from the name and an echo showing the template name

```
    Theme Name: ae-2020
    Template Name: illustration
    Template Post Type: illustration
    * 
    The template for displaying illustration pages
    * 
    Version: 1.0

    Description:
    */
```

The template name shows up in the page attributes dropdown. However when I view the post the index template is used. If I go to posts and view the "Hello World" post it uses my single.php template as expected.

What am I doing wrong?

Help appreciated.

David

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this can be helpful, this shows what prefixes and names to uses in wordpress hierarchy of templates
[image: Wordpress template hierarchy]

And here a link with wordpress documention of theme development https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: Yes, I've looked at that. I tried single-{post-type}.php didn't work. Is my custom post type a"post" or a "page" ?

Comment: It is a post page ;) I will tell you the structure i use

Comment: So in my theme folder i have the folder names custom templates inside this folder i make a template called page-illustration.php, on top of the page i write this php comment <?php /* Template Name: Illustrations */ ?> now after a reload WordPress will find your custom page template, in the sidebar dropdown on a page.

Comment: I can select the correct template in the drop down of my custom post and it saves it. But when I view the post it uses the index.php template. However, if I write a regular post and select the same template and view the post it uses the correct template.

Comment: I seem to havefixed it. There wassomething wrong with the metabox code. Not sure what but I redid it and it now works.

Comment: Nice, Good to hear!

Answer (score 0):

This template is use for illustration post type. That mean it's  just apply for illustration post type. While the "Hello world" is wp builtin post type and it's use single.php as template in default!

if you want to display the post using your template, change template's header into this:

```
Template Post Type: illustration, post
```